# Can we install a wordpress plugin remotely from one server to another?

Tags: wordpress, installation

I am working on a project where i need to install a plugin remotely. I tried WP_CLI but no luck. 
I have the credential of wp admin to login and the URL.
Is this possible?

Comment: you have "the URL" means another server hosted plugin url?

Comment: No I mean I have three things of other server  1.Admin Username | 2.Admin Password | 3 example.com
From example.com to example2.com

Answer (score 0):

Zip the plugin up if it's not already.  Login to the WordPress admin at http://url.com/wp-admin

Then in the admin go to Plugins > Add New and it will let you upload the zip file.  Then you need to go to Plugins and activate it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think you misunderstand the question. I mean Installing plugin from one wordpress to another wordpress2 remotely

Comment: If you have the access to files of the first WordPress install you can go into wp-content/plugins and zip up the directory containing the plugin you want to transfer over.  Then you can do as I suggested and login to the admin of site 2 and upload it.

Comment: I want to do it programatically. Its not only one wp its countless